# Displaying the 8-Bit image's bits

Tags: r, software-recommendations, cloudmasking

I have an 8-Bit cloud mask derived using cloud masking software from Sentinel-2 L1C and want to visualize each bit separately.
Is it possible?
If yes, what kind of software can I perform this task? (preferably, QGIS and R)

Comment: Take a looks at the `parse.bits` function in spatialEco. The help document is helpful in  how one would "visualize" a certain bit range. https://rdrr.io/cran/spatialEco/man/parse.bits.html

Comment: perfectly works!! and this function helps a lot to understand bits in case someone is in trouble with bits!